# Mineflayer bot crashes before starting digging

Tags: node.js, minecraft, mineflayer

```
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const pathfinder = require('mineflayer-pathfinder').pathfinder
const Movements = require('mineflayer-pathfinder').Movements
const { GoalNear } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder').goals
const inventoryViewer = require('mineflayer-web-inventory')

let options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 50599,
    username: 'Specchiopaura',
    version: '1.19.2'
}

const bot = mineflayer.createBot(options)

inventoryViewer(bot)



bot.once('spawn', () => {
    console.log('-CONNESSO-')
    bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder)
})


const mcData = require('minecraft-data')(bot.version)
const defaultMove = new Movements(bot, mcData)




bot.on('chat', (username, message) =>{
    args = message.split(' ')


    if(args[0] == 'quitta'){bot.quit()}


    else if(args[0] == 'trova')
    {
        Blocchi(args[1], args[2])
    }

    else if(args[0] == 'aprichest')
    {
        let chest = bot.findBlock({matching: mcData.blocksByName.chest.id, maxDistance: 64})
        const goal = chest.position
        bot.pathfinder.setMovements(defaultMove)
        bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalNear(chest.position.x, chest.position.y, chest.position.z, 1))
        bot.once('goal_reached', () => {
            bot.lookAt(chest.position.offset(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
            bot.openChest(chest)
        })
    }
})

async function Blocchi(bloccoDaTrovare, contatore) {
    for (let i = 0; i < contatore; i++) {
        let block = bot.findBlock({
            matching: mcData.blocksByName[bloccoDaTrovare].id,
            maxDistance: 10
        })
        console.log(block.position)
        if (!block) { return }
        await bot.pathfinder.setMovements(defaultMove)
        await bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalNear(block.position.x, block.position.y, block.position.z, 1))
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            bot.on('goal_reached', () => {
                bot.lookAt(block.position.offset(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
                bot.waitForTicks(10)
                bot.dig(block)
                resolve()
            })
        })
    }
}
```

when i try to run the "Blocchi" function by giving a block and a counter, the bot crashes before starting digging

this is the error

[image: 1]

by giving a block and a counter to the bot, it should find all the blocks in the maxDistance range and dig all of them. This didn't work as the bot crashes before digging. I tried to reduce the maxdistance from 10 to 2, but it didn't work. I also tried to see why it cannot dig the block and the console responded with "unkown reasons".

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same problem with my script so I know how it feels. So hopefully this helps :)

```
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const { pathfinder, Movements, goals } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder')
const GoalNear = goals.GoalNear

//Create Bot
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5555,
    username: 'StackOverFlow',
    version: '1.19.2'
})

//Load pathfinding plugin
bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder)


bot.on('chat', (username, message) =>{
    args = message.split(' ')


    if(args[0] == 'quitta'){bot.quit()}


    else if(args[0] == 'trova')
    {
        Blocchi(args[1], args[2])
    }

    // else if(args[0] == 'aprichest')
    // {
    //     let chest = bot.findBlock({matching:             
    //     mcData.blocksByName.chest.id, maxDistance: 64})
    //     const goal = chest.position
    //     bot.pathfinder.setMovements(defaultMove)
    //     bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalNear(chest.position.x,                 
    //     chest.position.y, chest.position.z, 1))
    //     bot.once('goal_reached', () => {
    //         bot.lookAt(chest.position.offset(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
    //         bot.openChest(chest)
    //     })
    // }
})



async function Blocchi(blockToFind, counter) {
    const mcData = require('minecraft-data')(bot.version)
    const defaultMove = new Movements(bot, mcData)

    for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        let block = bot.findBlock({
            matching: mcData.blocksByName[blockToFind].id,
            maxDistance: 10
        })

        console.log(block.position)

        if (!block) { return }
        
        bot.pathfinder.setMovements(defaultMove)
        bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalNear(block.position.x,             
        block.position.y, block.position.z, 1))
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            bot.on('goal_reached', () => {
                bot.lookAt(block.position.offset(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
                bot.waitForTicks(10)
                bot.dig(block)
                resolve()
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Also you may notice some of your code is commented out and this is because all I tested was the Blocchi function.

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT**

Hi! Sorry I just tested the code again but with multiple chests and it didn't work so I fixed it and this is the new code:

```
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const { pathfinder, Movements, goals } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder')
const GoalNear = goals.GoalNear

//Create Bot
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5555,
    username: 'StackOverFlow',
    version: '1.19.2'
})

//Load pathfinding plugin
bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder)


bot.on('chat', (username, message) =>{
    args = message.split(' ')


    if(args[0] == 'quitta'){bot.quit()}


    else if(args[0] == 'trova')
    {
        Blocchi(args[1], args[2], () => setTimeout(Blocchi, 20))
    }

    // else if(args[0] == 'aprichest')
    // {
    //     let chest = bot.findBlock({matching:             
    //     mcData.blocksByName.chest.id, maxDistance: 64})
    //     const goal = chest.position
    //     bot.pathfinder.setMovements(defaultMove)
    //     bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalNear(chest.position.x,                 
    //     chest.position.y, chest.position.z, 1))
    //     bot.once('goal_reached', () => {
    //         bot.lookAt(chest.position.offset(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
    //         bot.openChest(chest)
    //     })
    // }
})



async function Blocchi(blockToFind, counter) {

    const mcData = require('minecraft-data')(bot.version)
    const defaultMove = new Movements(bot, mcData)

    for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        bot.waitForChunksToLoad()
        let block = bot.findBlock({
            matching: mcData.blocksByName[blockToFind].id,
            maxDistance: 10
        })

        console.log(block.position)

        if (!block) { return }
        
        bot.pathfinder.setMovements(defaultMove)
        bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalNear(block.position.x,             
        block.position.y, block.position.z, 3))
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            bot.on('goal_reached', async () => {
                bot.lookAt(block.position)//.offset(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
                bot.waitForTicks(20)
                let promise = bot.dig(block)

                await promise
                resolve()
            })
        })
    }
    bot.pathfinder.setGoal(null)
}
```

The way I fixed your code btw was by:

1. Waiting for the new chunks to load before mining a new chest
2. Setting the pathfinding goal to 'null' before setting a new goal
3. Removing some of your unnecessary 'await's
4. Adding a timeout to the Blocchi function so that the bot/world has time to reload (this shouldn't effect how quickly you can type the command in chat by what my testing shows me)

So I hope this helps and it was fun to try and fix your code as it improved some bugs in my other scripts.

Thanks and bye!